# Framework applications using interface without heap memory allocation?

Tags: c++, interface, frameworks, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to create a framework for applications to use in my microprocessors. I am using Arduino IDE to compile and deploy the programs.

Since the microprocessors often have low heap memory, I want to only use stack memory if possible.

**Minimial example:**

The whole example code can be seen [here](https://github.com/smartskaft2/ExamplesForHelp/tree/master/arduinoFramework).

I will describe the parts I think is most interesting.

---

**iMinExApplication** (interface):

```
class iMinExApplication 
{
    public:
        virtual void initialize() = 0; // pure virtual
        virtual void execute()    = 0; // pure virtual

        virtual ~iMinExApplication() = default; // Virtual destructor
};
```

---

**tMinExApplication** (extension of interface, only used by the framework):

```
class tMinExApplication
{
    public:
        ...
        tMinExApplication(iMinExApplication* app, const char name[]) : App(app)
        {
            strcpy(Name, name);
        };
        ...
        void execute()    { App->execute(); };

    private:
        iMinExApplication* App;
        char Name[32]; 
};
```

---

**tMinExCoordinator** (master, calling added apps)

```
class tMinExCoordinator
{
    public:
        ...
        void addApp(iMinExApplication* app, const char name[]) 
        {
            tMinExApplication* tmpPtr = new tMinExApplication(app, name); // HERE!
            Applications[++NumApps] = tmpPtr;
            tmpPtr = nullptr;
        };
        ...
        void runApps()
        {
            for (auto& app : Applications) {
                // Frequency check
                // ...
                app->execute();
            }
        };

    private:
        tMinExApplication* Applications[];
        int NumApps;
};
```

---

**tMyApp** (user defined app, using the inherited interface)

```
class tMyApp : public iMinExApplication {
  ...
```

---

*minExSketch* (Arduino IDE sketch)

```
#include "tMinExClasses.hpp"
#include "tMyApp.hpp"

tMinExCoordinator coordinator{};
tMyApp tmpApp{};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  coordinator.addApp(&tmpApp, "TEST");
  coordinator.initializeApps();
}

void loop() {
  coordinator.runApps();
}
```

---

The above works. But the apps are allocated in heap memory, since it uses the keyword `new` (`'HERE!'` in the `tMinExCoordinator` class definition, line 57 in *tMinExClasses.hpp*).

I cannot seem to get it to work without it.
In what other way could I implement this, but only allocating memory in stack memory?

Requirements:

- Stack memory allocation
- The interface is to be used.

I have though of smart pointers, but am unsure if they use heap memory or not. Also, I wanted the minimal example as clean as possible.

Comment: @JaMiT, thank you for finding (and correcting) that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot seem to get it to work without it. In what other way could I implement this, but only allocating memory in stack memory?*

You can pre-allocate a byte array of sufficient size, and then use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to construct objects inside of that array (see [std::aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to help you with that).  Polymorphism only requires pointers/references to work at runtime, not dynamic alllocations.

```cpp
template<std::size_t MaxApps>
class tMinExCoordinator
{
    public:
        ...

        tMinExCoordinator()
        {
            Applications = reinterpret_cast<tMinExApplication*>(appBuffer);
        }

        ~tMinExCoordinator()
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NumApps; ++i)
                Applications[i].~tMinExApplication();
        }

        void addApp(iMinExApplication* app, const char name[]) 
        {
            if (NumApps >= MaxApps)
                throw std::length_error("");

            new (&appBuffer[NumApps]) tMinExApplication(app, name);
            ++NumApps;
        }

        ...

        void runApps()
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NumApps; ++i)
            {
                auto& app = Applications[i];
                // Frequency check
                // ...
                app.execute();
            }
        }

    private:
        typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(tMinExApplication), alignof(tMinExApplication)>::type appBuffer[MaxApps];
        tMinExApplication* Applications;
        std::size_t NumApps = 0;
};
```

```cpp
tMinExCoordinator<1> coordinator{};
...
```

The `std::aligned_storage` documentation linked above has an example `static_vector` class that uses a fixed memory buffer, which will be on the stack if the vector is constructed on the stack:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    std::size_t m_size = 0;

public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};

        // construct value in memory of aligned storage
        // using inplace operator new
        new(&data[m_size]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }

    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]);
    }

    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos])->~T();
        }
    }
};
```

You can use that class in your coordinator, with some minor additions to it so it can work with loops, eg:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    std::size_t m_size = 0;

public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};

        // construct value in memory of aligned storage
        // using inplace operator new
        new(&data[m_size]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }

    // Access an object in aligned storage
    T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos]);
    }

    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]);
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return m_size; }
    std::size_t capacity() const { return N; }

    // iterator access to objects
    T* begin()
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0]);
    }
    T* end()
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[m_size]);
    }
    const T* cbegin() const
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[0]);
    }
    const T* cend() const
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[m_size]);
    }

    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos])->~T();
        }
    }
};

template<std::size_t MaxApps>
class tMinExCoordinator
{
    public:
        ...

        void addApp(iMinExApplication* app, const char name[]) 
        {
            Applications.emplace_back(app, name);
        }

        ...

        void runApps()
        {
            for (auto& app : Applications)
            {
                // Frequency check
                // ...
                app.execute();
            }
        }

    private:
        static_vector<tMinExApplication, MaxApps> Applications;
};
```

> I have though of smart pointers, but am unsure if they use heap memory or not.

By default, they rely on `new` and `delete`, and thus dynamic memory.  Though, you *can* supply them with pointers to stack memory, if you also supply them with custom deleters that won't free that memory.

Comment: That seems really promising, thank you! However, I am a bit confused. It does use `new` with some extended stuff (`new(&data[m_size])`), what does this do? Furthermore, I thought `new` always allocated the memory on the heap. Will it be allocated on the stack if done compile-time?

Comment: Let's pretend I didn't ask the question about `new(...)` and instead read the link you so kindly provided. Sorry.

Comment: I tried searching for answers to my new found questions elsewhere. Is it correct that by allocating the memory first, using the `new` keyword could skip allocating any more memory (in the heap) but instead use the one you provide (e.g. on the stack)? Will `int a;` `a.~int();` `int* b = new(&a) int();` store `b` on the stack, while `int* b = new int();` store it on the heap?

Comment: @Smartskaft2 `a.~int();` is not valid in your example, but otherwise the rest is correct. `new` allocates on the heap and then calls the constructor on that memory, whereas `placement-new` calls the constructor on pre-existing memory that you specify. And then `delete` calls the destructor on the memory and deallocates it, whereas with `placement-new` you call the destructor yourself and skip the deallocation

Comment: Yeah that `~int()` was a wild guess. But I guess my point was proven anyway. Thank you for pointing it out, there are lots of small things like that that will save headaches later on. I will definitely try it. Hopefully, the Arduino IDE will accept the methods. Its compiler is sometimes somewhat outdated (e.g. `std::make_unique` does not seem to be supported).

Comment: I do not have any hardware to test the answer with at the moment. However, it compiles with Arduino IDE. Awesome! Thank you for your help.